# Not able to apply changes for wireless driver in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ubuntu-20.04

I have been using ubuntu some older versions for a while . And few weeks back I installed ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot . And I have never faced this problem in the Wireless network to detect wifi.

I am not able to apply changes to the wireless settings

[image]

Also I have the proprietary drivers for devices option enabled

[image]

I am sure my wireless adapter works properly . Since I have no problems with the wifi in my dual boot Windows 10 OS.

For your information I have mentioned the wireless information below

```
    (base) aadithya@aadithya-Precision-5520:~$ sudo lshw -c network

  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:edc00000-edc01fff
```

I have installed the necessary driver for the device which is recognised by the intel. And had followed the below steps and performed a reboot

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-5.4-rc2-1
make clean
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

**Still my wireless device is not detected. Kindly looking forward for some help.**

Regards

Aadithya

Comment: This looks like a question for https://askubuntu.com/.  It's not about programming; you're not *writing* wifi drivers, just trying to use them, so it's not a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have this exact same problem, Dell Precision 5520 and Ubuntu 20.04. Any luck tracking down a solution?

Comment: Haha .. Even my laptop is Dell Precision 5520 ...Now I feel like this is some kind of a dell ubuntu issue

Answer (score 0):

Have your try typing this line to check whether is the wireless driver is in there?

as sometimes you have plug it in and it is not registered in it

```
ip a
```

it should look something like this
with wl1...., wlan0, w1x456fg.....
[1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH2UK.jpg)

Comment: 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

This is the output I am getting . Now what should I do

Comment: It doesn't seem to have a wireless drive in it

Comment: are you using Ethernet connection or wireless connection?

Comment: Currently to access the internet in my computer I am using USB Tethering.  I am not able to use a wireless connection . Also I am not using Ethernet

Comment: can you let me know is the other device connected to the same network?

Comment: I am able to ping the ip ... And so yes both the devices are now connected to the same network. Are you suspecting that my computer is not able to get an ip to access the internet via wifi